# I want to call Zabbix Event.get api in post man

Tags: zabbix

How can I test Zabbix `event.get` API in post man?

```
event.get
```

Comment: Try http://monitoringartist.github.io/zapix/. It is  a "Postman" for Zabbix.

Comment: Thank you its really nice answer.

Comment: Can you please tell me how use Zabbix Api in mobile app, android
and how to generate auth key.

Comment: How to retrieve data from Zabbix APIs for the unavailability slots for any host?